# Rename a graph with sparql update

Tags: sparql, linked-data

Is possible to rename a graph using sparql update?

The only way through that I see is this:

```
INSERT {GRAPH uri:graphNEW {?s ?p ?o}}
WHERE  {GRAPH uri:graphOLD {?s ?p ?o}};
DROP GRAPH uri:graphOLD
```

but I'm not 100% sure that all the triples and attributes (like langue tags and xsd format) will be copied in the new graph.

Is there a cleverer way to do it?

EDIT: question improved thanks to Roman Susi suggestion

Comment: Maybe DROP GRAPH <yourgraph> will help?

Comment: yep! DROP GRAPH resolve the problem of the "empty graph". Thank you!

Comment: There are other ways of writing this (e.g. replace `GRAPH` with equivalent `USING` and `WITH`), but it all amounts to the same thing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-update/#graphManagement

```
MOVE uri:graphOLD TO uri:graphNEW
```

which will replace `uri:graphNEW`

```
ADD uri:graphOLD TO uri:graphNEW
```

which will add all of old into new and keep existing triples in `uri:graphNEW`.

Answer (score 1):

Graphs can be made empty of records with DELETE, but to remove the graph itself DROP GRAPH directive is needed:

```
DROP GRAPH <yourgraph>
```